# select revision in two tables and use inner join table translation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have 4 tables:
***rating***, ***university***, ***school*** and ***translate***
Receives an evaluation rating of university or school and translate contains the translation information.

**rating**

```
user | business_id | rate
1    | 1           | text my rate
```

**university and school**

```
business_id | translate_id
1           | 1
```

**translate**

```
translate_id | text   | language
1            | street | en
2            | strada | it
```

I need to grab all the reviews User ns university and school tables and use the translation package.
I am using the query below, but I doubt it is the best way.
I'm finding it a bit complex and was wondering if there are other simpler alternatives strong text.

***my query***

```
select
    A.* , innerjoin.name , innerjoin.address , innerjoin.type
from rating as A
inner join (
    select t.address , B.id , B.name , "university" as type from university as B
        inner join translate as t on t.id = B.address where t.language = "en"

    union all

    select t.address , B.id , B.name , "school" as type from school as B
        inner join translate as t on t.id = B.address where t.language = "en"
) innerjoin
on innerjoin.id = A.id
where A.student = "John"
```

***my output - EN***

```
0 => Array
     rate => #2 my rate
     name => school-1
     address => street
     type => school
1 => Array
     rate => #3 my rate
     name => university-1
     address => mall
     type => university
2 => Array
     rate => #1 my rate
     name => school-2
     address => avenue
     type => school
```

***my output - IT***

```
0 => Array
     rate => #2 my rate
     name => school-1
     address => strada
     type => school
1 => Array
     rate => #3 my rate
     name => university-1
     address => centro commerciale
     type => university
2 => Array
     rate => #1 my rate
     name => school-2
     address => viale
     type => school
```

Comment: You will have to clarify your question. Some of the text is garbled: "grab all the reviews User ns university", while some is imprecise and unlear "use the translation package". Also, your example SQL refers to `t.key` but the example table doesn't have this column.

Comment: my english is not good ... I get all revisions of a User in stabelas 'university' and 'school' and use the translate table to translate the address. thanks

Comment: Not criticizing your english (I couldn't even ask a question in any other language). I'm just pointing out where the question is unclear, which could lead to confusion, the wrong answer, or people ignoring it.

Comment: I thought showing the tables, query and output, would be easier to understand... My query is working correctly and translates the content. I think a complex query, you know say if there is another way to redo?

Comment: Your example tables and SQL still do not agree. In the SQL there are references to table `hotel` and column `address` which are not in the sample tables. Given that you seem to be trying to translate address, it is a bit difficult to advise you what you need when I can't tell what you have got. Please edit the question.

Comment: I had changed the tables to facilitate and forgot to change, now the tables have changed, but the question'll edit in another hour or until terminated by of this. thank you